# Find consecutive lines with specific strings and modify file based on table

Tags: text-processing

I have a text manipulation problem that I have been unable to solve. Say I have a text file like the one below (text.txt). There will be cases in which a line with `/locus_tag` is followed by a line with `/gene` and others where it is not. I want to find all lines in which `/locus_tag` is not followed by `/gene` and then use a table (table.txt) like the one below to match the `/locus_tag` to a `/gene` and add that `/gene` to my text file after its `/locus_tag`.

Any idea on how to do this would be great.

```
/locus_tag="LOCUS_23770"
/note="ABC"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_23780"
/note="DEF"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_23980"
/note="GHI"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_24780"
/gene="BT_4758"
/note="ONP"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_25780"
/gene="BT_4768"
/note="WZX"
```

**Table**

```
/locus_tag       /gene
LOCUS_00010      BT_4578
LOCUS_00020      BT_4577
LOCUS_00030      BT_2429
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your linked files, this works

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ =]+"; OFS="="}
     BEGINFILE{fno++}
     fno==1{locus["\""$1"\""]="\""$2"\""; }
     fno>1{if (old ~ /LOCUS/ && $0 !~ /gene/) print "/gene", locus[old]; old=$3; print}
    ' table file1
```

Before

```
                     /locus_tag="LOCUS_00030"
                     /note="WP_011108293.1 hypothetical protein (Bacteroides
```

After

```
                     /locus_tag="LOCUS_00030"
/gene="BT_2429"
                     /note="WP_011108293.1 hypothetical protein (Bacteroides
```

Since you are unfamiliar with `awk` a walkthrough

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ =]+"; OFS="="}
# set up the input field separator as any group of spaces and/or =
# and set the output field separator as =

     BEGINFILE{fno++}
     # Whenever you open a file, increment the file counter fno

     fno==1{locus["\""$1"\""]="\""$2"\""; }
     # if this is the first file (i.e. table) load the array `locus[]`
     # but wrap the fields in "..." so that they are exactly like the data file entries

     fno>1{if (old ~ /LOCUS/ && $0 !~ /gene/) print "/gene", locus[old]; old=$3; print}
     # if this is a data file
     # if the current value of old (i.e. the previous line) is a LOCUS
     # and && this line ($0) isn't a gene
     # add a gene by indexing into the locus array based upon the value of old
     # because old contains the last LOCUS we found
     # in all cases
     #    set old to the 3rd field on the current line,
     #       which on any LOCUS line is the string "LOCUS_?????" and
     #    print the current line
     # See note below re $2 vs $3 and FS

    ' table file1
    # your input files, table must be first, you can have more data files if you want
```

Or without the multichar `FS` then keep `old=$2` because it doesn't break on the whitespace before the text in your data file, which the multichar does.

The below sets the field separator depending on which file you are reading `FS=(fno==1)?" ":"="`. Space for the table and `=` for the data

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="="}
     BEGINFILE{fno++;FS=(fno==1)?" ":"="}
     fno==1{locus["\""$1"\""]="\""$2"\""; }
     fno>1{if (old ~ /LOCUS/ && $0 !~ /gene/) print "/gene", locus[old]; old=$2; print}
    ' table file1
```

Provided the table file is not so huge as to eat memory.

And put in a test to insert a message at missing genes if it suits more than just the empty `/gene=`

```
fno>1{if (old ~ /LOCUS/ && $0 !~ /gene/) print "/gene", (old in locus)?locus[old]:"\"GENE_MISSING_AT_LOCUS\""; old=$3; print}
```

Change the field reference for `old` to match which version of `FS` you are using

```
                     /locus_tag="LOCUS_00020"
/gene="GENE_MISSING_AT_LOCUS"
                     /note="WP_008765457.1 hypothetical protein (Bacteroides
```

**Edit**

Looking at the sample file you linked to there is simply an issue in the difference in formatting between the sample above and your actual data which messed with the field numbers. `old=$2` just needed to be changed to `old=$3`. Corrected above.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your reply. At first I was not able to get this as you describe. I was then able to do it by deleting `fno==1` and `fno>1`, eventhough it appends the _table_ at the top of the file. Thus, with the following code:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ =]+"; OFS="="}
     BEGINFILE{fno++}
     {locus["\""$1"\""]="\""$2"\""; }
     {if (old ~ /LOCUS/ && $0 !~ /gene/) print "/gene", locus[old]; old=$2; print}' table file1`

I obtained:

Comment: `/locus_tag       /gene
LOCUS_23780      BT_4577
LOCUS_23980      BT_2429
/locus_tag="LOCUS_23770"
/gene=
/note="ABC"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_23780"
/gene="BT_4577"
/note="DEF"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_23980"
/gene="BT_2429"
/note="GHI"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_24780"
/gene="BT_4758"
/note="ONP"
/locus_tag="LOCUS_25780"
/gene="BT_4768"
/note="WZX"`

The table at the top is not a problem, as I can just delete it. But when I apply this to my real file, I just get `gene=` inserted, without the gene name. I have tried many different variants of your code but without success as I don't know much awk

Comment: I had posted a simpler version of my file and maybe that is the problem. I have now uploaded a subset of my file and table to: https://tinyurl.com/tk5rdma. When I run `awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ =]+"; OFS="="}
     BEGINFILE{fno++}
     fno==1{locus["\""$1"\""]="\""$2"\""; }
     {if (old ~ /locus_tag/ && $0 !~ /gene/) print "                     /gene", locus[old]; old=$2; print}' table_test.txt file_test.gbk > output_test.gbk` 

I get `gene=` inserted, but for e.g. LOCUS_00030 that has a match in table_test.txt does not get a gene name. If you can point out what I am missing, it would be great.